# Tell mypy that all elements of list are of same type

Tags: python, mypy

Say we have

```py
from typing import List

a: List[int] | List[str]

if all(isinstance(i, int) for i in a):
    reveal_type(a)
```

This gives us

```
main.py:6: note: Revealed type is "Union[builtins.list[builtins.int], builtins.list[builtins.str]]"
```

Is there a way to get `mypy` to recognise that `a` is a list of integers, or is the only solution here to use `cast`?

Comment: See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0647/#typeguard-type. Scroll down to the example function `is_set_of` and use that as a template to declare your own `is_list_of_ints`.

Comment: maybe have a look at type narrowing and, more specifically, TypeGuards: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: @NicolasForstner type narrowing can narrow a `int | str` to `int`, but not a `List[int] | List[str]` to `List[int]` unless type guards are used.

Comment: @MarioIshac True. The link I sent leads to a part of the Mypy documentation that includes TypeGuards, I should have made that more specific.

Comment: perfect, thanks!